# Bulk upload the files from local path to SharePoint Online Allow Ampersand and Pound?

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am using PowerShell PnP v3 on Win 10 to bulk upload files and folders to SPO. I am using the script from this page: [enter link description here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Bulk-upload-the-files-from-8932fc26), which works great. However, it will skip files and folders containing an ampersand (`&`) or a pound symbol (`#`). How can this code be updated to allow those characters?  I am a Powershell newbie so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$cred=Get-Credential  
$makeUrl ="https://sharepoint.com/" 
$sourcePath = "C:\foldername"; 
$topSPOFolder = "one\two"; 

# connect to spo online 
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $makeUrl -Credentials $cred

$fileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Recurse ;

foreach($aFileName in $fileNames) 
{ 
if($aFileName.GetType().Name -ne "DirectoryInfo")  
{ 
 $filepath= [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($aFileName.FullName)+"\" 
 $Urlpath= ($filepath.Replace($sourcePath, '')); 
 $foldername=$Urlpath.Replace("/","\"); 
 $fn=$topSPOFolder+"\"+$foldername; 
 Add-PnPFile -Path $aFileName.FullName -Folder $fn; 
 $fn=$null 
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, in case if filename contains special symbols (such as `#`) the following exception occurs for `Add-PnPFile` cmdlet:

> The argument must be a single file name and cannot contain path
>   characters.

And seems the *similar* issue has been already reported [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/issues/937)

Further analysis of [source code for `Add-PnPFile` cmdlet](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/master/Core/OfficeDevPnP.Core/Extensions/FileFolderExtensions.cs#L1754-L1755)

```
  if (fileName.ContainsInvalidFileFolderChars())
                throw new ArgumentException(CoreResources.FileFolderExtensions_UploadFile_The_argument_must_be_a_single_file_name_and_cannot_contain_path_characters_, nameof(fileName));
```

confirms (at least in `3.2.1810.0` version) that:

- `#` is not allowed
- `&` is allowed

But given the fact that [support for # and % in SharePoint Online and OneDrive for Business has been introduced](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/New-support-for-and-in-SharePoint-Online-and-OneDrive-for/ba-p/60357?OCID=AID681541_aff_7593_1243925&epi=je6NUbpObpQ-Y1AqWe5U9joT_0izhO1i6g&irclickid=c2881042Nd62d0b8bcc55c912f7e2c902&irgwc=1&ranEAID=je6NUbpObpQ&ranMID=24542&ranSiteID=je6NUbpObpQ-Y1AqWe5U9joT_0izhO1i6g&tduid=%28ir_c2881042Nd62d0b8bcc55c912f7e2c902%29%287593%29%281243925%29%28je6NUbpObpQ-Y1AqWe5U9joT_0izhO1i6g%29%28%29), not sure why `#` is still not allowed. So, i would consider it is a bug and recommend to report an issue in GitHub.

Meanwhile you could consider the following solutions:

**Option 1**

Utilize the following function to upload a file which mimics to some extent `Add-PnPFile` cmdlet:

```
Function UploadAFile() 
{
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [string]$PathName,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [String]$FolderName,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
  [String]$FileName
)

   $ctx = Get-PnPContext

   if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($FileName)){
      $FileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($PathName)
   }

   $folder = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileFolderExtensions]::EnsureFolder($ctx.Web,$ctx.Web.RootFolder, $FolderName)
   $fileUrl = [OfficeDevPnP.Core.Utilities.UrlUtility]::Combine($folder.ServerRelativeUrl, $FileName)

   $fci= New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
   $fci.Overwrite = $true
   $fci.Content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($PathName)
   $fci.Url = $FileName
   $uploadFile = $folder.Files.Add($fci)
   $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
   return $uploadFile
}
```

Example

```
UploadAFile  -PathName "./Guide #123.docx" -FolderName "Shared Documents"
```

**Option 2**

*Replace* all not supported special symbols using `-NewFileName` parameter of Add-PnPFile cmdlet, for example:

```
Add-PnPFile -Path "./Guide #123.docx" -Folder "Shared Documents" -NewFileName "Guide 123.docx"
```